# If $a$ and $c$ are odd primes and $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has rational roots, where $b\in I$, then prove that one root will be independent of $a$ and $b$.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, quadratics

I am having trouble with this tricky question on number theory and quadratic equations.

> If $a$ and $c$ are odd prime numbers and $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has rational roots, where $b\in I$, then prove that one root of the equation will be independent of $a$ and $b$.

So I thought of trying the following way:

If it has rational roots (say $u$ and $m$) then $u . m = a . c$ and *u + m = b*. As $a$ and $c$ are prime, $a + c = b$, and plugging this into the quadratic formula, we get one root will always be $-1$.

I am not sure if this proof is correct or if my final value is correct. Could someone please give a detailed proof?

P.S.: I couldn’t find any examples regarding my question so if you do, please include them too.

Thank You.

Comment: Can’t the roots be $m=1,u=ac$?

Comment: If it is that case, then it is independent, you just missed a case.

Comment: $um=c/a$, and $u+m=-b/a$.

Comment: @razivo I know this proof has a lot of holes, I had tried it using the discriminant method in which I got the same method, do you think it’ll be more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Since $ \ a \ $ and $ \ c \ $ are odd prime numbers, the Rational Zeroes Theorem proposes the candidates $$ \ x \ = \ \pm \frac{c}{a} \ , \ \pm \frac{c}{1} \ , \ \pm \frac{1}{a} \ , \ \pm \frac{1}{1} \ \ . $$

The factorization of the quadratic polynomial is $ \ ax^2 \ + \ bx \ + \ c \ = \ a·(x - r)·(x - s) \ \ , $ so the four factorizations that will produce the correct leading and constant terms are
$$  a·\left(x - \frac{c}{a} \right)·\left(x - 1 \right) \ \ , \ \ a·\left(x + \frac{c}{a} \right)·\left(x + 1 \right) \ \ , \ \ a·\left(x - \frac{1}{a} \right)·\left(x - c \right)  \ \ , $$ $$ a·\left(x + \frac{1}{a} \right)·\left(x + c \right) \ \ .   $$

The "middle coefficient" $ \ b \ = \ -a·(r + s) \ $ in these products of factors is one of
$$ -a  ·  \left(\pm \frac{c}{a} \   \pm  \ 1 \right) \ \ = \ \ \pm \ (c + a) \ \ \ \text{or} \ \ \  -a  ·  \left(\pm \frac{1}{a} \   \pm  \ c \right) \ \ = \ \ \pm \ (1 + ac) \ \ ,  $$
any of which is an integer.

Hence, one of the rational roots of the quadratic equation is $ \ \pm 1 \ $ or $ \ \pm c \ \ , $ which are independent of $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ \ . $

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost correct (assuming you mean by $I$ the set of integers). The only thing you miss is that if $a,c$ are prime, then you have $a+c=\pm b$ (which follows from the fact that $b^2-4ac$ must be the square of a rational number), so the possible values are $\pm 1$. You can get as many examples as you want just from the formula $a+c=\pm b$ you have (e.g. $(a,b,c)=(3,\pm 8,5)$).

P.s. Your formulas u * m = a * c and u + m = b look wrong, but if you have $a+c=\pm b$, your quadratic equation is just $ax^2 \pm (a+c) x + c =0$, which you can just solve and is essentially the same as using the formula you want to apply.

Comment: $b^2-4ac$ must be the square of an *integer*, $b^2-4ac=d^2$, say, so $4ac=b^2-d^2=(b+d)(b-d)$, so $2a$ and $2c$ are $\pm(b\pm d)$ with some appropriate choice of signs. From that, you can get $a+c=\pm b$.

Comment: I think a priori you only know that it is a square of a rational number. The fact that your $d$ is an integer follows from the supposition that $b$ is an integer. The rest of arguments is the same as what I thought.

Comment: You're **given** that $a,b,c$ are all integers, whence $b^2-4ac$ is an integer, and it's a standard result that if an integer is the square of a rational, then it's actually the square of an integer.

Comment: I do not know why you are so aggressive, but I am agreeing with everything you are saying.

Comment: My apologies, no aggression was intended. I am glad we are in agreement on the mathematics.

Comment: @PekoraUsada thank you so much, so is the answer supposed to be -1, because i tried it this way first and I was getting -1 as the answer so I tried another method and got the same answer so I thought both were wrong, thank you so much though